# Wordpress Cloning- Font Awesome CORS Error-

Tags: wordpress, cloning

### Backstory

So I am building a website for a friend.  First time using Wordpress.  I am hosting site at a domain I own.  He bought a domain for the site which he wanted to point at the site.  I went in and pointed his domain A record to my hosting Ip.

### Cloning

Then I decided to clone the site make his domain and addon domain.  This all worked great except for one thing.  The font awesome icons are not loading.  I am getting a variety of weird symbols ranging from asian writing to swords.  In the dev tools console I am getting a CORS error.  How do I fix this.  Like I said I am new to WP and coding in general.  I have basic understandings of things.  I will enclose screen shot.

### Questions

Why is the new site looking to the old site for the font.  The new site has the font in the same directory.
If it helps.  My main domain is www.benjaminadk.com.  WP is installed at /blog.  The new site is at /highpeakpt.com and contains an exact copy of /blog.

### Edit

I just looked at site on iphone and it is fine.  Now I am more confused.  It is something with my browser.  But i still need to fix this....it would stand to reason that everyone with chrome browser would see weird icons.
[image: screenshot of errors]

Answer (score 0):

All i had to do was a Hard Reload in Chrome.  I checked this site on safari and it was working so then it got me thinking.  Anyway Problem Solved.